# How to get the "real" function name inside another function?

Tags: c#

Sometimes there is need to have some reflection for debugging. But the way like

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters().[0].Name
```

returns parameter name, not the actual function name. How to find out the 'real' name for the function in this case?

```
void OuterFunction(Func<string, int> f)
{
   int result = f("input");
   // how to get here function name 'g' instead of 'f'?
}

int g(string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    return 0;
}

OuterFunction(g);
```

Comment: What would you like to get if you call `OuterFunction(x => 10)`?

Comment: Probably something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1495465

Comment: Have you tried using an Expression?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek 'lambda'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Method` property of the delegate `f`.

```
void OuterFunction(Func<string, int> f)
{
    int result = f("input");
    string name = f.Method.Name;
    //name has the value "g" in your example
}
```

Note that if you pass in a lambda, you'll get a generated name for that lambda's body, like `(Main)b__0`.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
f.Method.Name
```

And don't forget to correct g to return int for it to compile ;)

Comment: I just fixed the return type of `g` in the question.